# Unable to execute java application in Eclipse it is showing IOException

Tags: java, eclipse, ioexception

I am unable to run sample java application in eclipse IDE,
it is continuously showing the

> **java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory**

this error message

this is my screen shoot

[image: IOException screen shoot]

Comment: restart the system... works for me sometimes :)

Comment: I restarted eclipse for several times but it is showing same message

Comment: Not enough space, this means your system ran out of memory or swap space when Java tried to fork a process.